# Jira does not wait SQL Server to start

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, jira

I am using Jira 3.1 for task tracking. It works over SQL Server 2008 R2.

Recently I tried to use Jira as a service rather than running it from a command line. I have installed the service and put dependency from SQL Server service.

The problem, however, is that it seems that Jira service does not wait SQL Server to start completely. Webpage shows error, event log says:

Login failed for user 'jirauser'. Reason: Failed to open the explicitly specified database. [CLIENT: 127.0.0.1]

If I manually restart the service, everything is OK, so looks like the reason is indeed in bad timing.

Is there any standard way to overcome this difficulty? I can, of course, create some batch file to start Jira service after some fixed time, say it, 1 minute after reboot, but this solution is ugly.

Comment: I found that Atlassian (Jira makers) technical support is excellent, exceeded my expectations by far. You can try asking them.

Comment: haimg, not a bad idea :) wrote them.